# Java Regular Expression to find or replace first occurrence without losing tail text

Tags: java, regex

My Regular Expression

```
SOME_STRING: .+\;$
```

Original String

```
lorem ipsum; SOME_STRING: I_AM_OLD; tail text;
```

I need to replace  `I_AM_OLD` with `I_AM_NEW`, but my regular expression is replacing everything up to the end of the string and I'm losing the tail text.

I expected to have

```
lorem ipsum; SOME_STRING: I_AM_NEW; tail text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are "greedy" by default. The `.+` in your expression matches all characters until the last `;`.

One possible fix is to match only characters that are not `;`:

```
SOME_STRING: [^;]+;
```